# nuxt.js - "This page could not be found" on static page with base ./

Tags: build, static, http-status-code-404, nuxt.js, router

I tried to generate a static web site with nuxt, but when i open the `index.html` file, it show an infinite load screen with this JS error :

> fail to load element  whose source is « file:///_nuxt/42185af33c638e7022a3.js ».

so, after i have search,  i change `router.base` configuration by `./` and it throw this error :

> This page could not be found
>   Back to the home page

but when i click on `Back to the home page` it showing my home page.

Anyone have an idea how to open `index.html` file from static build ?
i explain my project : i wish to run my app with Capacitor so i need static build work fine.

Thank by advance and my apologies for my bad english write.

Comment: 1. Remove router base 2. Run `npm run generate` 3. open `index.html` file search for `/_nuxt/` and replace it with `_nuxt`

Comment: i think you mean : replace `/_nuxt/` by `_nuxt/`, i tried and it not work. i have edit my post, the error do not contained `/app/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i have found my problem to run my app with Capacitor, Android dont like underscore.

In `nuxt.config.js`, just change `_nuxt` to `nuxt`

```js
build: {
  publicPath: '/nuxt/',
  // ...
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I found two solution:

Solution 1 : **Make your project to "universal" instead "single page app"**
When you generate a static web app, it work fine when you run `index.html`. However, Capacitor display the page but don't recognize the router, so you can't switch page in your app.

Solution 2 : **Set `router` in nuxt.config.js in spa**
Add this configuration to nuxt.config.js :

```
router: {
  base: './'
  mode: 'hash'
}
```

it work when you open the `index.html` file in dist, but does not work with capacitor.

My request is therefore partially resolved.